# Ajax data element not picking up

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an error here I'm sure:

```
var username  = $("#username").val();
var password  = $("#password").val();
var login  = $("#login").val();
var remember  = $("#remember").val();
console.log(username, password, login, remember);  //this shows up fine
$.ajax({     
  url: 'php/login.php',                        
  //here i think
  data: {username:username,password:password,login:login,remember:remember}, 
  type: 'POST',    
  dataType: 'application/json',                   
  success: function(data)          
  { ....
```

Because when I get to my login.php I get undefined index on lines:

```
 <?php
 $username = $_POST['username'];  //here
 $password = $_POST['password'];  //here

if ($_POST['login']) //check if the submit button is pressed
{
   $remember = $_POST['remember']; and here
.....
```

I return in login.php further down:

```
 echo json_encode("true"); //or "false"
```

in the response pane in firebug:

```
 <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: username in         <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\www\php\login.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
 <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: password in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\www\php\login.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
 123123123<br />
 <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: login in  <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\www\php\login.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

Comment: `**data:` must be `data:` - remove the stars

Comment: i clicked on the B for bold so it put the ** in front

Comment: I put the comment above the line, so we could read it without scrolling

Comment: no! just omit `contentType: "text/plain",` it'll work just fine

Comment: thanks you , i took it out and still get the same error

Comment: So $POST[username], $POST[password] and $POST[remember] are undefined but $POST[login] is passing through ajax?

Comment: they are all undefined in login.php:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `php://input`
This allows you to read raw data. Since your are using application/json you must be getting data in raw

Comment: huh? not familiar with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
 $.ajax({ 
        url: 'php/login.php',
        data: JSON.stringify({'username':'username','password':'password','login':'login','remember':'remember'}),    
        type: 'POST',    
        dataType: 'json',   
        contentType: "application/json",                
        success: function(data)  {.....
```

Comment: thank you for that but i still get undefined index in login.php, i dont understand

Comment: try it once with your absolute url.

Comment: comment `dataType` & `contentType` and remove `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. I ran into the same issue before and this is the only way I can get JQuery to properly send the key/value pairs when you're using your own string as the key.

```
var username  = $("#username").val();
var password  = $("#password").val();
var login  = $("#login").val();
var remember  = $("#remember").val();
$.ajax({     
  url: 'php/login.php',                        
  data: "username="username + "&password="+password + "&login="+login + "&remember="+remember, 
  type: 'POST',    
  dataType: 'json',                   
  success: function(data)          
  { ....
```

Answer (score 0):

i am also getting same problem using this method $.ajax and passing everything by : separated but how i reslove this issue using the following snippet.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#submit').on('click',function(){
        var formdata ={
            username:$('#username').val(),
            password:$('#password').val(),
            message:$('#message').val(),
            submit:$('#submit').val()
        };
        var url=$('form').attr('action');
        console.log(url);
        console.log(formdata);
        var posting = $.post(url,formdata);
        posting.success(function(data){
            $('.success').empty().append(data.username);
          });

       });
    });
</script>
```

in this snippet .success is a vriable where it spit out the username after success. following is the sample PHP code.

```
  <?php
    foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
    {
        $result[$key] = $val;
    }
     header('Content-Type: application/json');      
     echo json_encode($result);
 ?>
```

try this method and let me know it does resolve your issue or not ??

Regards